# Problem running single django files from VS Code

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code

I have a big Django project that I work in, and I have a problem when I try to run a single .py file from the terminal (I have the correct env set in my VSCode), and it usually breaks when trying to import a module (another django app).

When I try to run the same file from PyCharm I have no issues and runs perfectly (using the same env)

[image: Output of VS Code terminal]

Haven't tried much, I have no idea where to start to try and tackle this issue, all I find in google is people using the wrong env, which is not the case here.

Comment: Try setting your PYTHONPATH variable: ´export PYTHONPATH='.'´ in the terminal.

Comment: It's always good to double check spelling. I am guessing you have already done this, but just for good measure I am leaving this comment.

Answer (score 0):

When you run a single file in a project but you have dependency on other files, you need to add the dependent modules path in PATH. You can do that by simply adding the following on top of your file.

```
import sys
# path to folder containing debt module(the parent folder of the debt folder)
temp_path = "C:/path/to/folder/containing/debt"
sys.path.append(temp_path)
```

Do remember to remove this or comment this piece of code before you publish your django project.

Why did we need to do this?
When you tried to import debt module, python tried to find where is this debt module and it couldn't find it, that is why it threw the error. So we need to give a path to python to search in, that is why we add the path to folder containing the debt module.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply! I've added that to the start of the file using `if __name__ == '__main__'`, so I don't have to remove it later but it's not working, I've tried a lot of configurations for the path, using wildcard (*) going into cobra(the folder containing debt), going into debt, and nothing is working, not sure why

Comment: you shouldn't add wildcard, there is no need for that. Can you share your directory setup? or where the debt folder is.